# How to draw corner grab indicators like ios5 in UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I don't know how to draw corner grab indicators in drawRect method.this is mycode:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.8f);

CGFloat colX1 = CGRectGetMaxX(rect)/3.0;
CGFloat colX2 = 2*colX1;
CGFloat rowY1 = CGRectGetMaxY(rect)/3.0;
CGFloat rowY2 = 2*rowY1;

CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, colX1, CGRectGetMinY(rect));  
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, colX1, CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, colX2, CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, colX2, CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect),rowY1);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect),rowY1);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect),rowY2);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,CGRectGetMaxX(rect),rowY2);

CGContextStrokePath(context);}
```

and in the init method :

```
 CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = (CATiledLayer *)[self layer];
    tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 4;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;
```

my screenshot is:
[image: myCropView]

I want to know how to draw my view  like this:
[image]

I really want to know the code to draw the corner grab indicators.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corners are just 8 extra lines drawn just to the outside of the box you're drawing. Inset your box a little bit and draw them at the corners of the frame. You need to draw the outside box in that case rather than using `borderWidth`. But it's just more `CGContextMoveToPoint` / `CGContextAddLineToPoint` calls. You seem to understand all the tools that you need already.

**EDIT** BTW, if you look carefully at the picture you posted, you'll note that the border is actually made of both black and white pixels. They may have drawn a white border with a width of 2 and then come back and drawn the 4 black lines along the edges. This could be a little easier to draw.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw this kind of the by one trick - design one image like same as your second screen shot & create one layer with this image and put on it.

This one is simple as I think.